# FHIR: Extending the Basic resource with extensions

Tags: hl7-fhir

I'm an absolute FHIR newbie and I'm trying to create a set of `StructureDefinitions` and examples for an upcoming medical project.

For this project, we need a very specific resource, which is not supported by any FHIR resource yet. Here's our use case:

We are placing sensors on our Patients while they execute certain exercises (e.g. a leg squat) - we capture the sensor measurements and based on those we assign a pre-calculated bio-mechanical body model to each individual Patient. Those body models are calculated and assigned somewhere else in our system (this process is not relevant here). In a first step, I would like to add all the pre-calculated body models itself to our FHIR dataset as resources - so that I'm able to output all existing body models in our system.

Such a body model consists of an unique identifier, a human readable title and a set of attributes which describe the body model. The crucial part are the attributes - those might vary for each body model and we don't know the set of possible attributes beforehand, hence I need a dynamic format representing key and value of each attribute. If I were to represent this in a simple json structure I'd look as follows:

```json
{
    "id": "0",
    "title": "SAMPLE_BODY_MODEL",
    "attributes": [
        {
            "key": "ATTRIBUTE_1",
            "value": "EXAMPLE_1"
        },
        {
            "key": "ATTRIBUTE_2",
            "value": "EXAMPLE_2"
        }
    ]
}
```

My goal now is to create a `StructureDefinition` corresponding to the custom resource I've described above.

Hence I looked up the topic of "custom resources" and found this article on the HL7 site: https://hl7.org/fhir/basic.html - explaining that the `Basic` resource should be used for custom resources.

So I went ahead and tried to create a basic resource and extending it:

```json
{
    "resourceType": "StructureDefinition",
    ...
    "type": "Basic",
    "differential": {
        "element": [
            {
                "id" : "Basic",
                "path": "Basic",
                "definition": "This element describes a general body model captured during an exercise or a movement, e.g. whilst doing leg squats."
            },
            {
                "id" : "Basic.id",
                "path": "Basic.id",
                "definition": "ID of the body model"
            }
            {
                "id": "Basic.extension:title",
                "path": "Basic.extension",
                "sliceName": "definition",
                "definition": "Title of the body model",
                "min": 0,
                "max": "1",
                "type":  [
                    {
                        "code": "string" // I know that's wrong, but I somehow would like to restrict this to a string only
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": "Basic.extension:attributes",
                "path": "Basic.extension",
                "sliceName": "attributes",
                "definition": "Attributes of the body model",
                // This is where I'm stuck - how do I define this to be a list of objects consisting of attributes key and value?
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

To sum it all up: How do I create a new `StructureDefinition` from a basic resource allowing me to specify a new required attribute named "attributes", which consists of one-to-many elements, which again contain the attributes key and value for the key and value of the body model attributes?

Hope this makes sense - otherwise please feel free to let me know and I'll try to rephrase my question.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, for a newbie, you're doing really well :)  (And nice job on framing the question well too!)

Your first extension slice has a few issues:

- sliceName should be "title", not "definition" - essentially the 'extra' bit in the id is the slicename
- The 'type' needs to be Extension.  (The type of all extensions is always Extension.)  However, you should also specify a specific *profile* on Extension that indicates the canonical URL the StructureDefinition you've used to define the 'title' extension.  That extension will have a context of Basic and will constrain extension.value[x] to be of type string and will also establish a fixed URL for extension.url.

Your second slice will be similar.  However, the profile on extension *it* points to won't constrain extension.value.  Instead, it'll slice extension.extension to have two slices, one with a fixed url of "name" and the other with a fixed url of "value".  There's an example [here](https://build.fhir.org/extension-devicerequest-patientinstruction.json.html) of a 2-element complex extension.  Your slice names and data types will differ, as will the context, but it should make a good model for you.

If you still have issues, add your revised version to your question and we'll see if we can help further.

Comment: Hey Lloyd!

Thanks a lot for your response. The example which you provided did the trick, think I got everything working now. Much appreciated! :)